# Most closely related leaves in a tree (ete3 package)

Tags: python, python-3.x, phylogeny, ete3

Hello I have a tree such as :

```
>>> print(tree)

   /-A
--|
  |   /-B
   \-|
     |   /-C
      \-|
        |   /-D
         \-|
            \-E

 tree=Tree("(A,(B,C,(D,E)));") (ete3 function)
```

And I'm looking for a way to see the closest leaves to a particular leaf.

Here for instance the leaves most closely related to `C` are `D` and `E.` 
The leaf most closely related to `D` is `E`
The the leaves most closely related to `B` are `C, D` and `E.`

Answer (score 0):

the definition of "closest" is tricky in this context, but what you describe can easily be achieved by the following code (note that the tree in your code was missing a parenthesis):

```
In [1]: from ete3 import Tree
   ...:
   ...: tree=Tree("(A,(B,(C,(D,E))));")
   ...: c_node  = tree & 'C'
   ...: for sister_node in c_node.get_sisters(): # there might be multifurcations therefore the loop
   ...:     print(sister_node.get_leaf_names())
   ...:
['D', 'E']
```